# Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element <attribute>

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, xml-parsing

I am parsing through a xml file using stax and writing the extracted data to the database.  It works for small files, but when I parse a large file, its throwing this exception. Looking at the xml file, it is gud according to the row and column given. Could any one please let me know, why is this happening?

```
com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element <attribute>
at [row,col   {unknown-source}]: [787,1401]
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:686)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2730)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1019)
at com.ctc.wstx.evt.WstxEventReader.nextEvent(WstxEventReader.java:196)

sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3625.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
 at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the actual file you are parsing, at least the section that's causing the error.

Comment: its generating different [row,col] while parsing, its not reproducing the same again and again.

Comment: how are you feeding the xml file to the Stax parser?  it looks like it is getting getting to the end of the stream too soon.

Comment: It looks for the .xml extension file from the directory and parses one file after another, once the file is parsed and written to database, it deletes the parsed file. It searches for the keywords which are given, searches for that particular word and parses from there.

Comment: i mean, are you using a simple FileInputStream?  something else?  is it possible these files are being manipulated by an external process while you are parsing them?

Comment: _Only a global tip:_ Validate/check the XML file so you know the structure is okay. Check maybe that the encoding is okay. Check global states, by resetting global variables to null again.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. The file structure in wstx-asl.jar and stax2-api-3.1.1.jar are similar. So, instead of picking from stax2-api-3.1.1.jar, it was wrongly picking up from wstx-asl.jar, due to which the exception was occuring. Removing the wstx-asl.jar from the classpath solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is not in library or in code. Please check the connectivity between your server and wsdl server. If you try curl . It may receive the customized network message, that should not able to part your code. So, consult with your network team and security team to allow this url. It will solve the problem